# Android: Compute color dynamically

Tags: android, colors, android-color

I have a Util class which is capable of creating color codes(decimal).

```
public class ColorUtils {

    private static final String RED = "ff0000";
    private static final String GREEN = "00ff00";
    private static final String BLUE = "0000ff";
    private static final String WHITE = "ffffff";
    private static final int RADIX = 16;

    public static int getColorShade(String deepShade, String lightShade, float percentage) {
        if (percentage > 100) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Percentage can not be more than 100");
        }
        int deepShadeCode = Integer.parseInt(deepShade, RADIX);
        int lightShadeCode = Integer.parseInt(lightShade, RADIX);
        int shadeDifference = deepShadeCode - lightShadeCode;
        int shadeOffset = (int) (shadeDifference * percentage)/100;
        return lightShadeCode + shadeOffset;
    }

    public static int getColorShade(String deepShade, float percentage) {
        return getColorShade(deepShade, WHITE, percentage);
    }

    public static int getRedColorShade(float percentage) {
        return getColorShade(RED, percentage);
    }

    public static int getGreenColorShade(float percentage) {
        return getColorShade(GREEN, percentage);
    }

    public static int getBlueColorShade(float percentage) {
        return getColorShade(BLUE, percentage);
    }

    public static int getWhite() {
        return Integer.parseInt(WHITE, RADIX);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to convert it to Android color? 
All I could find out is `ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.yourcolor)`
but this will take resource id in second arguments, I don't want to make color pallets in color.xml. Is there a work around?

Comment: Yes now you got it right. Basically my billing software will have fields "Total Billing Amount" and "Amount Paid". Depending on the fraction of total amount I will use shade of red for the item background. More the pending amount, darker will be the background color. And my view is basically list of such bills.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out finally. And it is working as expected now. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I scrapped the code above and simplified it using rgb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how you create the color, but if it can extract red, green, blue, then try this:

```
@ColorInt int color = Color.rgb(getRedColorShade(percentage), getGreenColorShade(percentage), getBlueColorShade(percentage));
```

Ref [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#rgb_31), this time it's pretty sure that this method is added from API level 1 and can be used instead of `valueOf`

Comment: This will work for me, but min API level set is 22 for my application.

Comment: What do you mean API level 22? Color class is added from API level 1 ref here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.

Comment: Color class didn't have support for the method valueof in API level 22